# Two different ruby versions on mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

I am setting up a simple ruby on rails app locally. It seems I have two different versions of ruby on mac and I would like to only use one. When I ran `bundle install`, it says `Your Ruby version is 2.7.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3`. Then, I changed the line `ruby '2.6.3'` in my gemfile to `ruby '2.7.1'`. With this it ran `bundle install` properly. However, when I run `rails server` it says `Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1`.
Why is it saying two different values for my Ruby version?
How do I get it to only use one version of Ruby?

If its relevant, I am on a mac and installed ruby using homebrew. If I run `ruby -v` in the terminal it says `ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]`. I'm not sure why it says I have ruby 2.6.3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are to different versions because Mac OSX already includes one by default for system scripts (2.6). Homebrew install another one that never overrides o reemplace the System Wide version.

You are looking for a "**Ruby Version Manager**", are tools that allow you to install and use different versions of Ruby, even per project.

The popular ones are RVM and rbenv. Personally, i choose **rbenv** and I think that is the most widely used of both. Example of use:

```sh
# Install ruby 2.7
rbenv install 2.7.1

# Make ruby 2.7 the default version
$ rbenv global 2.7.1

# Or make 2.7 the default versión only on a specific project
$ cd myproject
$ rbenv local 2.7.1
# this create a ".ruby-version" file
```

This webpage always have the most recent and easy to use tutorial for setup a Ruby environment, depending on the OS and version.

https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina#overview

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That looks like its used when someone wants to have and use multiple versions of ruby. I would like to only use one, just not sure why its currently saying I have two different versions.

Comment: Try to append “bundle exec” to your command, “bundle exec rails s”.

Comment: There are to different versions because Mac OSX already includes one by default for system scripts (2.6). Homebrew install another one that never overrides o reemplace the System Wide version.

Comment: The Ruby versions managers allow you to use only one version, no matters that tomorrow OSX delete the system wide or homebrew update to 2.8  or 3.0

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize one of the versions was from MacOS. Just downloaded ruby and rails with the gorails link you sent and its working great!

Comment: This worked and the tutorial was easy to follow on the link. The only thing that was left out was that you need to restart your terminal to see the changes take effect and the `ruby -v` command match what you set globally or locally

Answer (score 2):

You have two different versions of Ruby installed, because MacOS natively comes with a standard installation of Ruby.

You also have `rails` pointing to the system version of Ruby.  That version is usually under `/usr/bin/ruby`.  The Homebrew installed version of Ruby (which is what you want) is located under `/usr/local/bin/ruby` unless you specified a completely different root path to install your brew packages.

Running `brew config` will give you a short list of data about your Homebrew configuration.  Among them is an environment variable called `HOMEBREW_PREFIX`, which should look something like this:

```
$ brew config
....
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
....
```

I recommend placing `/usr/local/bin` first on your `PATH` environment variable so that you can easily use your brew packages via the CLI:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

You may also want to look into setting the following environment variables for whichever shell you are using (examples given):

- `RUBY_ENGINE=ruby`
- `RUBY_VERSION=2.7.1`
- `GEM_ROOT=/usr/local/etc/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.1` (alias for `GEM_HOME`)

`gem env` gives a lot of great information on how Gems is configured.

Answer (score 0):

I I had this exact problem and managed to fix it by running this command:

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.6.7
```

Note - I needed that version (2.6.7) please change it to the one you need

I found this on this blog post here - https://dev.to/rbazinet/fix-installation-of-ruby-using-rbenv-on-macos-big-sur-3432